# parsing a pdf with tables to text

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to parse this pdf document in text file. I am using iTextSharp dll for that purpose. My whole PDF document is parsing correctly except there is a table in the pdf document that has lines in it. It parses that table, but if there is some space in one cell of the table then i don't see that space in the converted text document. Below is the format of the table.

```
Col1    Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5 

1       Test1   2     5       Test6
2               3             Test7
3       Test6         9       Test8
```

The output that I see is like this:

```
1 Test1 2 5 Test6 <LF>
2 3 Test7<LF>
3 Test6 9 Test8<LF>

<LF> is line feed.
```

Is there any way, I can see those spaces too? Below is the PDF parsing code:

```
 Public Sub ExtractTextFromPdf(path As String)
        Dim its As ITextExtractionStrategy = New LocationTextExtractionStrategy()
        Dim HeadLine As String
        Using reader As New PdfReader(path)
            Dim str As New StringBuilder()

            For i As Integer = 1 To reader.NumberOfPages
                Dim thePage As String = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, its)
                Dim pdf31460Lines As String() = thePage.Split(ControlChars.Lf)
                For Each EachLine As String In pdf31460Lines
                    str.AppendLine(EachLine)
                    If EachLine.Contains("SNEW") Then
                        HeadLine = EachLine
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            InsertParsedFileHeader(str.ToString(), HeadLine)


            '  ParsedFileWithSeperator = Regex.Replace(ParsedFileWithSeperator, "\s+", "~")


        End Using
End Sub
```

I have been searching for this for 3-4 days and couldn't find the right answer.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I need to do it in .net-C# or VB.net

Comment: I would directly inspect the contents of EachLine on the lines which are missing the spacing. Is the spacing present there and getting stripped off later? Is there instead some other control character in it's place? If spacing is not present in eachline I'd take a look at pdf31460Lines and if nothing there then in thePage. If there is simply nothing to match/detect I'm not sure how you'd correctly insert the spaces.

Comment: There is space in pdf file, but not in the parsed text. There could be some other control character, but I opened it in notepad++ and couldn't see any control character.

Comment: If it's not there when you `GetTextFromPage()` it seems like the iTextSharp would need modification...

Comment: what kind of modification. I have been searching for this for a while. Any help or hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know enough about the underlying binary structure of PDFs to tell you what the modification would be, but presumably PDF has some designation for an empty table cell or has some other concept of table layout and spacing that iTextSharp is getting wrong. The modification would be in figuring out how to properly parse binary PDF data the represents table layouts and spacing and translating that back into strings / text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. I used pdfBox for this purpose. Its little bit slow, but it is completely free and very very accurate in parsing the pdf document. Below is the link to pdf box if someone is interested.

```
http://www.squarepdf.net/pdfbox-in-net
```